# Django, save only resized image, not the original

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

So I have this model in my Django project:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ... # resizing and saving the image
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Just a simple model with ImageField. I wonder how to save only resized image. As I know
"super().save(*args, **kwargs)" saves the original image with its original sizes. But it takes too long to save for example 10-15 MB photo. In my resizing logic the image is compressed and resized to about 1-3 MBs. And I want to save in my MEDIA root only this resized image and not the original one. I don't want the original image even appear in my project (it takes way too long to process this image while saving). How to avoid "super().save(*args, **kwargs)"?

Hope you got it, thanks in advance! Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of avoiding `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` you can use it. So your all images will be resized and saved as you want. You can change the logic of the example as you need.

```
pip install Pillow
```

inside your Image model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300, 300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Okay, so ```super().save(*args, **kwargs)``` saves 10 Mbs originally, and then I add my own logic. But I will not even use that image which is 10 mbs, why to load my server with this data? I have almost the same logic as your resizing part. But this is not what I need. I don't want to save that 10-15 mbs. Hope u got it

Comment: You are not saving a 10MB image you are editing the image before saving it. Think you have a compress action in your save function it will be SAVE only the edited image. As you mention in your question "I wonder how to save only resized image"

Comment: But you first call the **super save** method and then editing it and saving again the edited form. When you call **super save** method it first saves the original image and then you add your resizing saving logic

Comment: Calling the super().save() after editing doesn't work either. What is the difference between calling it earlier or sooner. The fact that I call it already saves the original image, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually, my function is not saving a second time. But you can pull the super save line to the down line. I updated my answer

Comment: What does it change, mate? I'll update mine as well. But this doesn't help at all :(